# Records in deleted table that are not in the delete statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers

We have a large number of databases with the same schema, which each have a table with triggers to sync records with another table in a central database. When the table is updated, inserted into, or deleted from, the table in the central database also has a record updated, inserted, or deleted.

We've been having records mysteriously disappear from the table in the central database. When researching the problem I found that when the insert/delete trigger fires there are records in the `deleted` table that are not from the current delete statement. They aren't even records in the same database. They look like the old values record for update statements on the same table in another database.

All the information I could find says records in the `deleted` table should be from the statement that caused the trigger to fire.

Can anyone explain why I'm seeing this behavior instead?

EDIT: This is what the insert/delete trigger looks like:

```
DECLARE @TenantID INT
SELECT @TenantID = ID FROM [CentralDB]..Tenants WHERE db = DB_Name()

INSERT INTO [CentralDB].[dbo].[TenantUsers]
   (..snipped list of columns...)
SELECT 
  ...snipped list of columns...
  FROM inserted 
  WHERE UserNameID NOT IN (0,6)

DELETE FROM [CentralDB]..TenantUsers WHERE UserNameID in 
    (SELECT UserNameID FROM DELETED WHERE UserNameID NOT IN (0,1,6))
```

And the update trigger:

```
DECLARE @TenantID INT
SELECT @TenantID = ID FROM [CentralDB]..Tenants WHERE db = DB_Name()

UPDATE [CentralDB].[dbo].[TenantUsers]
  SET ...snipped list of columns...
 FROM INSERTED i
 WHERE i.UserNameID = TenantUsers.UserNameID 
    AND i.UserNameID NOT IN (0,6)
```

Comment: In order to help you we would need to look into either your code, or a functioning crystal ball. I have it in good authority that there are no actively functioning crystal balls around, so...

Comment: I'm asking about how SQL Server populates the deleted table. Seeing my code doesn't help very much with that, much like you being a smart-ass doesn't help anything.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that's the source of your probems, and not the way the triggers are written? I'm speaking out of experience, I've seen people do magic with triggers before. And by magic, I mean that kind of trick where the magician makes stuff disappear in front of your eyes and you really can't figure out how he did it without some forensic analysis.

Comment: That's true enough, though it does really unlikely in this case (the db user doesn't even have permission to see records from other databases). Thanks.

Comment: This trigger fires on insert and delete, not update.

Comment: @JeffB then show us that one too please

Comment: @JeffB So I tested and it's NOT DB context...I suspect there's something else at play since if transactions in other DBs could kick off your triggers this would be a huge bug that I doubt would be overlooked.

Comment: @JNK We also don't reference other databases except for the central db. They're independent customer databases and the users we use don't have permissions to do any DML on a different customer db. Thanks for checking, though.

Comment: @JeffB One thing I would look for is an issue in your CentralDB..Tenants table.  If there's a bad record there it could cause this as well.

Answer (score 0):

You've probably done this but if records are being deleted which ought not to be then i'd go round the db's (or write a script too) and check the triggers which contain the delete statements only fire for inserts and deletes..  Maybe there is a rouge trigger which fires on update and executes the delete command?

Its a long shot..

Other than this i would check there are no other triggers in the chain which can delete from the central db table.

there appear to be no obvious issues with the trigger design